# How can I use a stack buffer overflow to make an attack

Tags: security, reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow

I am a IT Security student and I have to write a paper about a vulnerability in a real life case. I chose a small application that allows to create icons under Windows, which is vulnerable to a stack buffer overflow.
I've already had to do manipulations on exercise scripts (injecting shell code into a script that can be used in the Linux command line, etc.) but never on a real application.
Is it possible for you to help me to use the vulnerability to carry out some kind of "attack" or to execute a program function not supposed to be executed at that moment?

I didn't try to reverse the code yet, I will try to find where the program is storing the long string I use to make it crash, the size of the memory for this variable and the return address.

I found this app when trying to find a vulnerable app on Vulnerability Lab : https://www.vulnerability-lab.com/get_content.php?id=1609

You can also download the app from this link (the vulnerability is still present in the last version): http://www.aha-soft.com/iconlover/

PS : I've only been studying IT Security for a year and a half, so I am a beginner. Sorry if there are some mistakes in my text, I am french. This is one of my first post on this forum, I hope I did it well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.). We don't download apps to test for you or to complete your assignment. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: If you picked that application randomly, it might be very hard (or not) to actually exploit the vulnerability. Also exploiting bof in modern operating systems requires some advanced techniques so in your demo environment you may want to disable some protections like aslr and dep if applicable - it's still a nice task without those. Otherwise your question is a little too broad I'm afraid, you should probably do your research, try to come up with a solution and ask about a more specific problem so that we can actually help.

Comment: I am sorry for asking at the wrong place, I got an answer that is just perfect for me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already ready made exploits to do what you are asking for iconlover. see [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/38349). The script forces the application to open up calculator.exe which indicates a very severe security issue.

You can modify the given shellcode for RCE or to execute malicious programs (assuming you already have some form of access to the target system.)